# Surprised that Entity Framework is saving a detached Entity correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity class `Timecard`, I get this entity from this method:

```
public Timecard GetTimeCardForPerson(long timecardId) 
{
    return timecardContext.First(item => item.TimeCardId = timeCardId);
}
```

timecardContext is of type `TimecardContext: DbContext`.

I later make a change to the `Timecard` entity, the `Timecard` entity has a property:

```
public virtual ICollection<TimecardRow> TimeCardRows { get; set; }
```

which is initialized, in `Timecard's` constructor to a `HashSet` like so:

```
this.TimeCardRows = new HashSet<TimecardRow>();
```

I add a child `TimecardRow` I then call another method and this is its exact implementation and pass it the same Timecard instance as is returned from `GetTimeCardForPerson`:

```
public void SaveTimecard(Timecard timeCard)
{
    timecardContext.Entry(timeCard).State = timeCard.TimecardId == 0
        ? EntityState.Added
        : EntityState.Unchanged;


    timecardContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The passed in `Timecard timeCard` argument is not attached to the `timecardContext` and has a TimecardId > 0.

I am surprised that my new `TimecardRow` saves successfully as Entry(timeCard.State) is set to `EntityState.Unchanged`.

The EntityState.Unchanged tells my timecardContext that there is nothing to change, does it not? But all the same, the `TimecardRow` I added is inserted into the database when the `SaveTimecard` method is called.

Comment: Is the Timecard instance being returned from GetTimeCardForPerson the same instance you're subsequently making a change to and passing to SaveTimecard?

Comment: @thudbutt it is the same Timecard instance, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EntityState.Unchanged tells the context that nothing has changed for the *Timecard* entity.

The TimecardRow is a separate entity which EF will track separately so a call to SaveChanges will insert that entity.

The above assumes that the Timecard is already attached when passed to the Save method (which it will be if it's the same instance returned from the GetTimeCardForPerson method).

If the Id check in the Save method is there to cope with both detached and attached entities, would it be better to leave the state alone unless it is an id of 0?

Comment: When you do timecardContext.Entry(timeCard).State =  EntityState.Unchanged, you are attaching the entity to this context. So no surprise this new context start to track timeCard and its childs.

Comment: Thanks @E-Bat, I just checked, it is actually the same TimecardContext instance but you information is very helpful

Comment: @thudbutt, I think that the State = EntityState.Unchanged is intentional as the Timecard Entity Properties cannot be changed, they are readonly, but a client has the Timecard entity and could make changes